# Customize bottom navigation bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create a nav bar whose icons will look like this when active:

[image]

But mine looks like:

[image]

I usually use [bottom_navy_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/bottom_navy_bar).
So here is the code for it:

```
      BottomNavyBarItem(
        icon: _currentIndex == 0
            ? _buildActiveIcon(
                'assets/icons/navigation/home_white_icon.png')
            : _buildInactiveIcon("assets/icons/navigation/home_icon.png"),
        activeColor: Colors.black,
        inactiveColor: CustomColors.white,
        title: Text(
          "Home",
        ),
      ),
```

Code for active and inactive icon:

```
  Widget _buildInactiveIcon(String assetUrl) {
    return Container(
      height: 30,
      width: 30,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
        color: CustomColors.white,
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: ImageIcon(
          AssetImage(
            assetUrl,
          ),
          color: CustomColors.black,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildActiveIcon(String assetUrl) {
    return Container(
      height: 30,
      width: 30,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(60),
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: ImageIcon(
          AssetImage(
            assetUrl,
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

So can this be done with the help pf any package or do I have to create some sort of custom navbar?

Comment: What will be the view for inactive navItem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your solution:

1. [Full page Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4FdX.png)
2. [BottomNavigationBarItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVrNL.png)

BottomNavigatonBarItem Code:-

> BottomNavigationBarItem(
> icon: Container(
> width: 140,
> height: 35,
> decoration: const BoxDecoration(
> color: Color(0xffA3C2D4),
> borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
> child: Stack(
> children: [
> Container(
> width: 35,
> height: 35,
> decoration: const BoxDecoration(
> color: Colors.black, shape: BoxShape.circle),
> child: Icon(
> Icons.notifications,
> color: Colors.white,
> ),
> ),
> const Center(
> child: Padding(
> padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
> child: Text(
> "Notification",
> style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
> ),
> ))
> ],
> ),
> ),
> label: '',
> ),

Full Code:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          "Screen 1",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28),
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: 0,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
        onTap: (v) {},
        elevation: 0.0,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              width: 140,
              height: 35,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xffA3C2D4),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 35,
                    height: 35,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Center(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Home",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            label: '',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              width: 140,
              height: 35,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xffA3C2D4),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 35,
                    height: 35,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.black, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.notifications,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Center(
                      child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                    child: Text(
                      "Notification",
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
            label: '',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to only show home icon when I navigate to notifications?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: I've already modified the nav bar to my liking. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar)

[image]

Comment: That was not my question. Persistent nav and bottom navy bar are pretty much same. I wanted an active button as mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Check also the package [Salomon_bottom_navigation](https://pub.dev/packages/salomon_bottom_bar)